# how to test match in an xsl:apply-template?

Tags: xslt

In my second xsl:template match, how do I test for the match pattern? For example if the match patter is title, I want to output different value?

```
  <xsl:template match="secondary-content">
    <div class="secondary">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="block/content | content" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="title|content|block/content">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that is simple, short and that doesn't contain any explicit logical XSLT instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, +1.

In the second template, use this test expression:

```
test="self::title"
```

or

```
test="local-name() = 'title'"
```

For example, you can use

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="self::title">
    <someThing>foo</someThing>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: @steve: good. BTW you can "accept" this answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

Why not split it into two separate template rules? It seems strange to have a single template rule to handle several cases when the logic is different for the different cases. Use separate rules, and if the logic is complex, factor common/shared logic into a named template (or if you're feeling ambitious, use xsl:next-match or xsl:apply-imports for the common logic).

Answer (score 2):

**It is almost always better not to have conditional logic within a template body**.

**Therefore, instead of**:

```
<xsl:template match="title|content|block/content">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- conditional processing here -->
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**write**:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <!-- Some processing here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content|block/content">
    <!-- Some other processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

BTW, matching `content|block/content` is equivalent to the shorter `content`.

**Therefore, the last template can be further simplified to**:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
    <!-- Some other processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Valid point. But it would help to know why (and therefore *when*) it is better to use matching rules than to use `choose`/`if`. I assumed the OP had combined the templates into one on purpose, e.g. because much of the processing was the same, with a relatively small conditional part. But maybe that is not the case.